# Should I Use a Comma before the Second “and”

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> Please enter your email and password, and click on the “Log In”
>   button.

Should I use a comma before the second “and”?

Comment: While you should use a comma, as @mikhailcazi says, you could also say something like "...enter your email and password, *then* click ...", which further cements the order of the required actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because the second *'and'* is used as a conjunction for two clauses.

[Clause 1]***, and*** [Clause 2]

Try [this](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/020204whencommabfand.htm) page. :)

Comment: But a clause requires a subject and a predicate. 'Clause 2' doesn't itself have a subject independent of that of 'Clause 1'.

Answer (score -1):

Either way, but I would remove it.

On one hand, commas are often best taken out. The sentence still works without the comma, so that rule of thumb would say to remove it.

On the other hand, the comma helps to group the first command (entering details) and separates it from the second (clicking).

On balance, I would remove it.

Comment: One can argue that the commands share an ellipsized subject ("you") and that the construction is that of a compound predicate rather than two independent clauses. Omitting the comma could be justified on that ground.  However the comma clarifies the distinct uses of *and*, as you noted, and the extra comma seems a small price to pay for that much clarity.